# HANDLE in function won't work

Tags: c++, winapi

Im trying to make this code draw a circle in the window of my application:

```
    Draw Circle;
    Circle.DrawCircle(hwnd, i*200+5, j*200+5, i*200+194, j*200+194, 7, (255, 0, 0));
```

the class I use, called Draw.cpp, looks like this

```
    #include "Draw.h"
    #if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
    #define _UNICODE
    #elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
    #define UNICODE
    #endif

    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;


    Draw::Draw()
    {
    }

    void DrawCircle(HWND vhwind, int xPosTopLeft, int yPosTopLeft, int xPosBotRight, int yPosBotRight, int width, vector <int> rgb)
    {
         HDC hdc;                          
         PAINTSTRUCT ps;                   
         hdc = BeginPaint(vhwind, &ps);
         HPEN hPenOld;
         HPEN hLinePen = CreatePen(PS_DASH, width, RGB (rgb[0], rgb[2], rgb[2]));
         hPenOld = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, hLinePen);
         Arc(hdc, xPosTopLeft, yPosTopLeft, xPosBotRight, xPosBotRight, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
         SelectObject(hdc, hPenOld);
         DeleteObject(hLinePen);
    }
```

the headerfile, called Draw.h looks like this:

```
    #ifndef DRAW_H
    #define DRAW_H
    #include "Draw.h"
    #if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
    #define _UNICODE
    #elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
    #define UNICODE
    #endif

    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;


    class Draw
    {
        public:
            Draw();
            void DrawCircle(HWND vhwind, int xPosTopLeft, int yPosTopLeft, int xPosBotRight, int yPosBotRight, int width, vector <int> rgb);
        protected:
        private:
    };

    #endif // DRAW_H
```

The problem has something to do with the "HWND vhwind" i think. 
The error message says: "error: no matching function call to 'Draw::DrawCircle(HWND__*&, int, int, int, int, int,  int)'"
Could any of you guys please tell me what i do wrong?

Comment: The error message has a line number. It does not point to any code you've posted. Further, you don't have a method named DrwawCircle.

Comment: Ensure that you have declared DrawCircle() function in Draw.h  file. Also in the cpp file, right now you have `void DrawCircle` change that to `void Draw::DrawCircle(`

Comment: The types of the arguments you're passing don't match the function signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
Draw Circle;
Circle.DrawCircle(hwnd, i*200+5, j*200+5, i*200+194, j*200+194, 7, {255, 0, 0});
```

The last argument, written as `(255, 0, 0)`, is interpreted a single `int`.

**--- EDIT ---**

Sorry: my solution is good if you're using C++11 or C++14.

In case you're using C++98, you should prepare a `std::vector<int>`; something like

```
Draw Circle;
std::vector<int> rgb;

rgb.reserve(3);
rgb.push_back(255);
rgb.push_back(0);
rgb.push_back(0);

Circle.DrawCircle(hwnd, i*200+5, j*200+5, i*200+194, j*200+194, 7, rgb);
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.